# Attributes are not changing in the placed order

Tags: commerce, caching

I have a commerce site with T-shirts as products. I have added custom attributes of size and type.

By default L Size is selected. But even if the user changes the size to something else say M or S, in the order that is placed the size is still being shown as L.

I am assuming that this is because of caching. I currently have authcache enabled with Mem-cache in the backend.

I checked the XHR call that is being made. I see that the size that is being sent in the call is the one selected by the user. But however when the order is placed it still says L. Any help where to start debugging would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You said "But even if the user changes the size to something else say M or S, in the order that is placed the size is still being shown as L." Where is it still shown as L ? In the cart page ? Check out page ? After order is completed in view order page ? Please add more details otherwise this question will be closed as "Unclear what you're asking "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue with page level caching system for anonymous users in Drupal. Please subscribe to the open [issue](https://drupal.org/node/2171129) on the authcache issue tracker, then you will be notified as soon as this is fixed. There is also a report in the [Drupal Commerce Queue](https://drupal.org/node/2049665)